# is there any way to pre-calculate an element's wrap on Ctrl+?

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, word-wrap

I have a webpage where HTML within a certain `DIV` (called `content`) is converted to PDF.
The `content` div can have more divs within it, each containing text, and absolutely positioned. Each of these `divs` is called a "textbox"

The problem is that the PDF turns out not **exactly** like the HTML within `content`. Sometimes text gets wrapped onto two lines in the PDF, although it wasn't that way in the HTML. This happens when the following is true:

- A `textbox` containing text appears to be fine in the current view, but if the user were to zoom in (using Ctrl+), then the text wraps to the next line within its div.

So what I need to do is somehow detect that *if the HTML were zoomed in, there would be a text-wrap*, and if so, then expand the width of the element a tad so that the PDF doesn't end up wrapping onto a new line.

Is there any way to detect that? Or anything else that comes to the same effect?

Comment: I suggest that you've locked yourself into a solution, whereas what you really need to do is focus on the problem. Figure out what the differences are (probably fonts/kerning) and perhaps calculate a reasonable margin of error (literally) to add to your HTML containers so that they will be big enough in the PDF too.

Comment: The problem is font-hinting - different browsers render fonts differently in terms of width. So on a Mac the same line of text with the same font size and the same font family might take up less space across than it would on a PC, because of machine/browser fonts hinting. Do you have any idea about this stuff? If I were to grab the width of a span or paragraph, would it capture that difference?